# Rails 4 - Passed variable from controller to js.erb file is null

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

My partner and I are working on a project and we'd appreciate some help. We've read a lot of answers on stackoverflow already, watched several railscasts, etc but are still not able to resolve our issue. Thanks for the help in advanced. And please be nice, we're sorta new to rails :)

We have a polymorphic relationship set up for 'likes'. A user is able to like and unlike a 'bloc'. On our bloc index, we list out all the blocs. Within the loop for each bloc, a _like_button partial is rendered. This partial has the following code:

**_like_button.html.erb**

```
<% if liked?(bloc, current_user) %>
    <%= link_to bloc_like_path(bloc, current_user.id),method: :delete, class: "bloc-unlike", :remote => true do%>
      <i class="fa fa-heart "></i>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to bloc_likes_path(bloc, @like), method: :post, class: "bloc-like", :remote => true do%>
      <i class="fa fa-heart "></i>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
<span class="right"><%= bloc.likes.count %></span>
```

Our index page has the following code in the loop to render out the partial:

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="like" class="bloc-likes">
   <%= render 'likes/like_button', :bloc => bloc %>
</div>
```

Our likes_controller has the following code (this is similar for destroy):

**likes_controller.rb**

```
def create
     # some stuff here to figure out likes. It works for sure, therefore omitted
     if @like.save
        @bloc = Bloc.find(@like.likeable_id)
        render :toggle, :bloc => @bloc
      end
end
```

The 'render :toggle' in the likes_controller refers to a toggle.js.erb file that contains the following:

**toggle.js.erb**

```
$("#like").html("<%= escape_javascript render ('like_button') %>");
```

SO, here is the issue. When we click the like, the save goes through, but we run into a problem with passing the 'bloc' back to the partial when it reloads. It needs it to determine if the if-statement is true or not. We've tried a couple things but it just doesn't seem to work. For example, adding ':bloc => params[:bloc]' after the render code in toggle.js.erb, and I don't even remember what else we did because its been a complete mush and our brains will explode.

Really appreciate you taking the time to read this and helping us out - we are quite close to jumping out of windows.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the first render line

```
render :toggle, locals: {bloc: @bloc}
```

Then pass pass bloc again

```
$("#like").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'like_button', locals: {bloc: bloc}) %>");
```

Comment: That gives a syntax error, but if we change it to ...render ('like_button'), bloc: bloc %>"); we get the following error 

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `bloc' for #<#<Class:0x007ff636b5e260>:0x007ff638381ba8>):
    1: $("#like").html("<%= escape_javascript render ('like_button'), bloc: bloc %>");
  app/views/likes/toggle.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_likes_toggle_js_erb__2670016663781878873_70347740929260'
  app/controllers/likes_controller.rb:33:in `create'

Answer (score 0):

Try to using some debugger, for example pry.
In your controller action add:

```rb
def create
  if @like.save
    @bloc = Bloc.find(@like.likeable_id)
    binding.pry
    render :toggle, :bloc => @bloc
  end
end
```

it would pause execution and provide you a command prompt where you can inspect your variables and execute ruby code.
Also add `binding.pry` in you template.
More info here: https://github.com/pry/pry